# how to get users ip address in java

Tags: java

While this may seem simple, i have tried the usual request.getRemoteAddr(), request.getRemoteHost() but i keep getting my servers address. Something about my configuration, im getting my gateway ip. Does anyone know how to get the acutal users IP address?

thanks

Comment: Do you have a proxy or another web server (Apache, etc) in front of your application server?  Have you tried accessing the server remotely and do you get the same result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there's some proxy between you and the user, then you might have to look at the [`X-Forwarded-For` header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For). Note that this isn't guaranteed to work either, but if you only need "good enough", then it might suffice.

Comment: A warning about X-Forwarded-For.    Some implementations will actually add a list of IP Addresses that may be in the chain, so you might need to anticipate which one was the original address.

<pre>
X-Forwarded-For: client1, proxy1, proxy2
</pre>

Comment: @Trey: thanks for the comment re: IP Address chain. I have to modify some logging code to use X-Forwarded-For and now I know to anticipate this possiblity, rather than being surprised by it.

Answer (score 2):

Apache Http will integrate a secure mechanism to handle X-Forwarded-For header with mod_remoteip (1).

Here are a Tomcat valve RemoteIpValve (2) and a servlet filter XForwardedFilter (3) to integrate the X-Forwarded-For and X-Forwarded-Proto headers respectively at the Tomcat and WAR levels with the same secure mechanism as mod_remoteip does.

Thanks to this, `request.getRemoteAddr()`, `request.getRemoteHost()`, `request.isSecure()`, `request.getScheme()` and `request.getServerPort()` will expose the values transmitted by X-Forwarded-For and X-Forwarded-Proto rather than the values of the preceding proxy / load balancer.

Hope this helps,

Cyrille

cleclerc@xebia.fr

(1) http : / / httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_remoteip.html

(2) http : / / code.google.com/p/xebia-france/wiki/RemoteIpValve

(3) http://code.google.com/p/xebia-france/wiki/XForwardedFilter