# How to get IP Add In JAVA like following link

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to get users ip address in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804428/how-to-get-users-ip-address-in-java)
>   [Get IP address with URL string? (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9286861/get-ip-address-with-url-string-java)

link is :

```
"http://automation.whatismyip.com/n09230945.asp"
```

the above link return External IP.

I try to make my own code to get my IP like above link

my code is

> String my_own_ip =InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();

so how to get this IP

in this code return my internal IP

I am in LAN Connection my LAN IP is 192.168.0.109

and external IP is 27.54.180.156

```
I want 27.54.180.156
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Your answer to question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9286861/get-ip-address-with-url-string-java

Comment: Did you try `InetAddress.getByName("www.external-name-of-your-host.com")`?

Comment: @HardikLotiya What do you mean by my IP Address?

Comment: hello smit , this above link you posted in that case at time required IP Of URL String but I want my own IP

Comment: your code _will_ return your IP address, so what's the problem?

Comment: Use the @ symbol followed by the user name, to send messages to commentators.

Comment: @MouseEvent  My code return "192.168.0.109" BUT I want "27.54.180.156"

Comment: I don't know much about networking or security, but is it a good idea to be posting your ip like that on a public web site?

Comment: @RichardJPLeGuen What are your intentions? ;-}

Comment: done by following Links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10322506/how-to-get-external-ip-succesfully

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10322506/how-to-get-external-ip-succesfully

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `getLocalHost()` - that will return your [local host](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost).

```
InetAddrsss addy = InetAddress.getByName("www.stackoverflow.com");
System.out.println(addy.getHostAddress());
```

Note that you'll want to omit the protocol, `http://`:

```
InetAddrsss addy = InetAddress.getByName("http://www.stackoverflow.com"); // throws an exception
System.out.println(addy.getHostAddress());
```

... and equally the path:

```
InetAddrsss addy = InetAddress.getByName("www.stackoverflow.com/questions"); // throws an exception
System.out.println(addy.getHostAddress());
```

Comment: please refer edited code

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you assume your computer has access to the external IP address when, in fact, it does not. Only the router and outside connections have access to the IP address.

That being said, your best option is to use a website like http://icanhazip.com or http://checkip.dyndns.org (or the one you supplied, for that matter, http://automation.whatismyip.com/n09230945.asp) and connect to it using an HTTP Get on your Java client, like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485708/how-do-i-do-a-http-get-in-java) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442791/send-http-get-request-with-header). Once you get the HTML page back, parse it to find the IP address. This can be done using regex since these are very simple HTML pages that don't require extensive DOM parsing:

```
String html = ... ;
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d{1,3}(\\.\\d{1,3}){3}");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(html);
matcher.find();
String ip = matcher.group(0);
```

The trick is finding a website with a free API that you can call as many times as you want. The two I listed above don't have any limits as far as I know.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use the bit of code in a jsp page and print it into the body of the document.

```
<%@page import="java.net.InetAddress" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
 <% String my_own_ip =InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();%>
    <%=my_own_ip%>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But that return 192.168.0.109 and my external IP is "27.54.180.156"

Comment: This is the exact code the OP provided, put in a JSP - but the OP makes no mention of JSP, or any kind of web programming. On top of all that, the use of scriplets is discouraged. -1